# CAAnimation delegate methods not being called on delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, caanimation

The delegate is my view controller.

I am setting the delegate via:

```
CABasicAnimation theAnimation;
theAnimation.delegate = self;
```

Then I configure the animation and add the animation to the layer, and I verified it is animating correctly on the device.

However, I cannot get this delegate method to be called:

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
    NSLog(@"animationDidStop called.");
}
```

Any ideas?

Also, I could not find anywhere the protocol my view controller adopts for the `CAAnimation` delegate methods.  I thought all delegate objects had to adopt a protocol?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an objective-c and iOS expert, but conforms your controller to the protocol?

Comment: __Be aware that `CAAnimation`'s `delegate` is strong, so you might need to set it to `nil` to avoid retain cycles!__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also, I could not find anywhere the protocol my view controller adopts for the CAAnimation delegate methods. I thought all delegate objects had to adopt a protocol?

Delegation and formal protocols are orthogonal concepts:
Formal protocols are a pretty recent addition to the Objective-C programming language — as a matter of fact, they were introduced *after* CoreAnimation (née LayerKit).

The way of doing things prior to the introduction of `@protocol` — and the way `QuartzCore` still works — was declaring a category on `NSObject` as a so called "Informal Protocol". It is only recently that Apple started formalizing these — see `NSURLConnection` for such an example, which gained it's delegate protocols with the current releases of iOS/OS X.

After this brief aside on history, now to your problem:

If what you are showing is a verbatim copy of your code, then that cannot work. In fact, if you aren't using ARC you are pretty lucky that the above code doesn't crash due to a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. You should totally set the value of `animation` to something meaningful before trying to send messages to it...

Comment: Thanks for the excellent protocol history. What I am using, I now know, is an informal protocol, and you have to declare the delegate methods in the header file to get them to be called.  The above does not show my complete code because I was able to get the animation to work correctly on the device as I stated toward the top of my question.

Comment: The snippet in the question doesn't crash because sending a message to nil is valid and has no effect.

Comment: @AnthonyMattox yes, messaging `nil` is fine. No, without ARC that variable is probably not `nil`: Under _manual_ reference counting, object variables are not treated differently from primitive variables, so if you declare them but not assign a value to them, you’d have random garbage in there. ARC, however, guarantees initialization of local object variables with `nil`.

Comment: My mistake, @danyowdee. I seem to take ARC for granted and missed that detail of the explanation.